# Why does my program crash when transferring strings between char pointers in C?

Tags: c, algorithm, pointers, char, memcpy

I'm having a problem with memcpy() in c right now, and hope someone can help.

My program allows users to enter a string into a char pointer, and then calculates all possible permutations. As the permutations are generated (the user input pointer is changed into a permutation), the permutation is copied into a second char pointer via memcpy. It works perfectly, unless the string has two or more different repeating characters (eg. "CCBB" or "AADD"). If the user enters anything like this, memcpy (or even strcpy) causes the program to crash.

```
void Permute(char * word, char ** printPerm, int start, int end)
{   
    if (start == end)
    {
        memcpy(printPerm[permIndex], word, strlen(word) + 1);
        ++permIndex;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = start; i <= end; ++i)
        {
            Swap((word + start), (word + i));
            Permute(word, printPerm, start + 1, end);
            Swap((word + start), (word + i));
        }
    }
}

void Swap(char *a, char *b)
{
    char temp;
    temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```

I've tried allocating more memory to both pointers but it's proved futile. Everything else works except for this.

Because I'm using gcc on Windows (MinGW), the details of my crash aren't shown. It simply says "perm.exe has stopped working". I used a series of printf() statements and found that the program is crashing on the memcpy() line.

A few details about the code:

The "word" char pointer holds the user's input. It will be morphed into permutations by the program, and it's contents will be dumped into "printPerm". "printPerm" the the char pointer array that holds the permutations, and will later be used to print the permutations when they've been sorted alphabetically and any duplicate entries have been removed. "permIndex" is the index of "printPerm" and is iterated every time a permutation is added to "printPerm".

Sorry I don't have more details, but using a text editor and gcc means I don't get much of a debugger. It seems any method of tranferring data between the pointers will crash the program ONLY if the string contains two or more different repeating characters.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: "users to enter a string into a char pointer" - Bad idea! A pointer is not an array. You definitively don't want users to input anything **into** a pointer!

Comment: I tested your `Permute` function by writing my own `main` function and it seems to be working fine for the inputs that I tested. I tested for `AABB`, `AABBB`, etc. I dont think there is issue in `Permute` function that you have shown here. Can you edit your question and add the function from where you are calling Permute? There will be issue if `printPerm[permIndex]` is does not point to valid memory, and if `permIndex` is not initialized correctly.

Comment: Show the declaration of printPerm. It is the likely failure  point.

Comment: I suspect the problem is that your code that figures out how large to make the `printPerm` array is counting unique characters. So "ABCD" has 4 unique characters and the number of permutations is computed correctly. But "AADD" has only 2 unique characters. Your `Permute` function doesn't take into account repeated characters, so it will still try to compute 24 permutations. You need to show us how you're determining the size of the `printPerm` array.

Answer (score 0):

You are lucky: my crystal ball just came back from repair! Let's see if it works now:

```
// ALL CHECKS OMMITTED!
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static int permIndex;

// place the two functions you published here

// Uhmmm...well...but we need one
int factorial(int n)
{
  int f = 1;
  do {
    f *= n;
  } while (--n);

  return f;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int f,i;
  char **pperm;
  char *word;
  size_t length;

  if (argc < 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s string\n", argv[0]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  // work on copy
  length = strlen(argv[1]);
  word = malloc(length + 1);
  strcpy(word, argv[1]);

  // You either allocate memory as you need it but as you compute
  // all combinations first, you need the whole memory for them
  // at once. That means the amount of memory needed is known in
  // advance and can be allocated at once

  f = factorial((int) length);
  // allocate memory for an array of (length)! pointers to char
  pperm = malloc(f * sizeof(char *));
  for (i = 0; i < f; i++) {
    // allocate memory for the n characters plus '\0'
    pperm[i] = malloc(length + 1);
  }

  Permute(word, pperm, 0, length - 1);

  // do something with the list

  // print it
  for (i = 0; i < f; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", pperm[i]);
    // we don't need the memory anymore: free it
    free(pperm[i]);
  }
  // free that array of pointers mjentioned above
  free(pperm);
  // free the memory for the input 
  free(word);

  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

This is one of several ways to do it.